# Haskell function to check differences between two lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, compare, fold, zipwith

I want to write a function that checks if two lists are "almost" equal. The first parameter `d` is used for precision - the difference between the elements must not exceed `d`.

For example, `nearlyEqual 0.5 [2,5] [2.5, 5.1]` equals `True`, but `nearlyEqual 0.1 [2,5] [2.5, 5.1]` equals `False`.

I wrote this but it is not working:

```
nearlyEqual :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
nearlyEqual d xs ys = foldr(&&) True $ zipWith (\x y -> abs(x-y)<=d)
```

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's a typo, but you're not passing `xs` and `ys` to your function.

```
nearlyEqual d xs ys = foldr(&&) True $ zipWith (\x y -> abs(x-y)<=d)
```

should be

```
nearlyEqual d xs ys = foldr(&&) True $ zipWith (\x y -> abs(x-y)<=d) xs ys
```

at least for it to typecheck.

A clearer implementation would make use of `all`, which is of type `Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`, and of the function composition operator `(.)`:

```
nearlyEqual d xs ys = all ((<= d) . abs) $ zipWith (-) xs ys
```

where `zipWith (-) xs ys` is element-wise difference of the two lists, and `all` verifies that the predicate `(<= d) . abs` holds for *all* of the elements of that list; the predicate, given an argument, applies `abs` to it, and then `(<= d)` to the result.

Comment: @blair You are also using both `d` and `e` inconsistently for the tolerance.

Comment: And a misleading whitespace policy, imho. `foldr(&&)` and `abs(x-y)` makes a lot look like languages where you need parenthesis to enclose the argument(s).